# How to eliminate derefs?

Tags: rust, pointers

## Spoiler: [Advent of Code 2020 Day 8](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/8)

> Your flight to the major airline hub reaches cruising altitude without incident. While you consider checking the in-flight menu for one of those drinks that come with a little umbrella, you are interrupted by the kid sitting next to you.
>
> Their handheld game console won't turn on! They ask if you can take a look.
>
> You narrow the problem down to a strange infinite loop in the boot code (your puzzle input) of the device. You should be able to fix it, but first you need to be able to run the code in isolation.
>
> The boot code is represented as a text file with one instruction per line of text. Each instruction consists of an operation (acc, jmp, or nop) and an argument (a signed number like +4 or -20).
>
> - acc increases or decreases a single global value called the accumulator by the value given in the argument. For example, acc +7 would increase the accumulator by 7. The accumulator starts at 0. After an acc instruction, the instruction immediately below it is executed next.
> - jmp jumps to a new instruction relative to itself. The next instruction to execute is found using the argument as an offset from the jmp instruction; for example, jmp +2 would skip the next instruction, jmp +1 would continue to the instruction immediately below it, and jmp -20 would cause the instruction 20 lines above to be executed next.
> - nop stands for No OPeration - it does nothing. The instruction immediately below it is executed next.
>
> For example, consider the following program:
>
> nop +0
> acc +1
> jmp +4
> acc +3
> jmp -3
> acc -99
> acc +1
> jmp -4
> acc +6
>
> These instructions are visited in this order:
>
> nop +0  | 1
> acc +1  | 2, 8(!)
> jmp +4  | 3
> acc +3  | 6
> jmp -3  | 7
> acc -99 |
> acc +1  | 4
> jmp -4  | 5
> acc +6  |
>
> First, the nop +0 does nothing. Then, the accumulator is increased from 0 to 1 (acc +1) and jmp +4 sets the next instruction to the other acc +1 near the bottom. After it increases the accumulator from 1 to 2, jmp -4 executes, setting the next instruction to the only acc +3. It sets the accumulator to 5, and jmp -3 causes the program to continue back at the first acc +1.
>
> This is an infinite loop: with this sequence of jumps, the program will run forever. The moment the program tries to run any instruction a second time, you know it will never terminate.
>
> Immediately before the program would run an instruction a second time, the value in the accumulator is 5.
>
> Run your copy of the boot code. Immediately before any instruction is executed a second time, what value is in the accumulator?

I'm solving AoC problems with Rust this year and ran across something where I *feel* there has to be a better, more Rust-like solution.  In my loop, I'm derefing mutable references quite a bit and someone suggested smart pointers, but I don't know how that would look in my existing implementation.

How would you address the mutability on `Instruction`'s members?

```rust
pub enum Instruction {
    Jump { address: i32, is_noop: bool, has_run: bool },
    Acc(i32, bool),
}

impl Instruction {
    pub fn new(s: &str) -> Self {
        let instruction = &s[..3];
        let address: i32 = (&s[4..]).parse().unwrap();

        match instruction {
            "jmp" => Self::Jump { address, is_noop: false, has_run: false },
            "nop" => Self::Jump { address, is_noop: true, has_run: false },
            "acc" => Self::Acc(address, false),
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}

pub fn parse(s: &str) -> Vec<Instruction> {
    s.split('\n')
        .map(Instruction::new)
        .collect()
}

pub fn solve(input: &mut Vec<Instruction>) -> i32 {
    let mut acc = 0;
    let mut idx = 0;

    loop {
        match &mut input[idx] {
            Instruction::Jump { address, is_noop, has_run } => {
                if *has_run {
                    break;
                }
                *has_run = true;
                if !*is_noop {
                    idx = (idx as i32 + *address) as usize;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            Instruction::Acc(data, has_run) => {
                if *has_run {
                    break;
                }
                *has_run = true;
                acc += *data;
            }
        }

        idx += 1;
    }

    acc
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn p1_example() {
        let input = "nop +0
acc +1
jmp +4
acc +3
jmp -3
acc -99
acc +1
jmp -4
acc +6";
        let mut input = parse(input);
        let acc = solve(&mut input);

        assert_eq!(acc, 5);
    }
}
```

--- Part Two ---

> After some careful analysis, you believe that exactly one instruction is corrupted.
>
>  Somewhere in the program, either a jmp is supposed to be a nop, or a nop is supposed to be a jmp. (No acc instructions were harmed in the corruption of this boot code.)
>
>  The program is supposed to terminate by attempting to execute an instruction immediately after the last instruction in the file. By changing exactly one jmp or nop, you can repair the boot code and make it terminate correctly.
>
>  For example, consider the same program from above:
>
>  nop +0
>  acc +1
>  jmp +4
>  acc +3
>  jmp -3
>  acc -99
>  acc +1
>  jmp -4
>  acc +6
>
>  If you change the first instruction from nop +0 to jmp +0, it would create a single-instruction infinite loop, never leaving that instruction. If you change almost any of the jmp instructions, the program will still eventually find another jmp instruction and loop forever.
>
>  However, if you change the second-to-last instruction (from jmp -4 to nop -4), the program terminates! The instructions are visited in this order:
>
>  nop +0  | 1
>  acc +1  | 2
>  jmp +4  | 3
>  acc +3  |
>  jmp -3  |
>  acc -99 |
>  acc +1  | 4
>  nop -4  | 5
>  acc +6  | 6
>
>  After the last instruction (acc +6), the program terminates by attempting to run the instruction below the last instruction in the file. With this change, after the program terminates, the accumulator contains the value 8 (acc +1, acc +1, acc +6).
>
>  Fix the program so that it terminates normally by changing exactly one jmp (to nop) or nop (to jmp). What is the value of the accumulator after the program terminates?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what part of *dereferencing mutable references* is supposed to be a problem, or how smart pointers could "solve" it. I mean, "dereference" is pretty much the main useful thing you do with a reference. Is this just about reducing the number of `*`s in your source code? Why?

Comment: @trentcl It's about ergonomics mostly and learning what patterns are available for mutability; having to deref everything feels sloppy

Comment: *and someone suggested smart pointers* — did you ask that person for specifics of **how** it would help? If you just want to reduce the `*`, you can try something like `match *&mut input[idx] { Instruction::Jump { address, is_noop, ref mut has_run }` to dereference `address` / `is_noop` in the pattern match

Comment: @Shepmaster negative; it was a one-off comment when I was asking for feedback on a different platform.  Is `*&mut` different from `mut`?

Comment: `mut` by itself isn't syntactically valid in this context. You should actually use `match input[idx]` as it's less tangled :-) See also [What's the difference between placing “mut” before a variable name and after the “:”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster gotcha, in my head `*` is inverse to `&`.  that answer was illuminating.  So it sounds like for my case here, the "best" approach is to deref in the match argument so I don't have to deref literally everything else?

Comment: That's what I would do without looking at the bigger picture of your code (thus why the comments and not an answer) See also [What does &* combined together do in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41273041/155423)

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having derefs is OK, as others mentioned in comments. I just wanted to address the existence of *explicit* derefs. We can use *implicit* derefs. This requires splitting off our `Instruction` type into `JumpInstruction` and `AccInstruction`, which is common practice, done for example in Rust's AST. We have:

```rust
pub enum Instruction {
    Jump(JumpInstruction),
    Acc(AccInstruction),
}

pub struct JumpInstruction {
    address: i32,
    is_noop: bool,
    has_run: bool,
}

pub struct AccInstruction {
    data: i32,
    has_run: bool,
}
```

Then it's a matter of changing each `*field` to `jump.field` or `acc.field`. Also, some code must be accomodated:

```rust
impl Instruction {
    pub fn new(s: &str) -> Self {
        let instruction = &s[..3];
        let address: i32 = (&s[4..]).parse().unwrap();

        match instruction {
            "jmp" => Self::Jump(JumpInstruction {
                address,
                is_noop: false,
                has_run: false,
            }),
            "nop" => Self::Jump(JumpInstruction {
                address,
                is_noop: true,
                has_run: false,
            }),
            "acc" => Self::Acc(AccInstruction {
                data: address,
                has_run: false,
            }),
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}

pub fn parse(s: &str) -> Vec<Instruction> {
    s.split('\n').map(Instruction::new).collect()
}

pub fn solve(input: &mut Vec<Instruction>) -> i32 {
    let mut result = 0;
    let mut idx = 0;

    loop {
        match &mut input[idx] {
            Instruction::Jump(jump) => {
                if jump.has_run {
                    break;
                }
                jump.has_run = true;
                if !jump.is_noop {
                    idx = (idx as i32 + jump.address) as usize;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            Instruction::Acc(acc) => {
                if acc.has_run {
                    break;
                }
                acc.has_run = true;
                result += acc.data;
            }
        }

        idx += 1;
    }

    result
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn p1_example() {
        let input = "nop +0
acc +1
jmp +4
acc +3
jmp -3
acc -99
acc +1
jmp -4
acc +6";
        let mut input = parse(input);
        let acc = solve(&mut input);

        assert_eq!(acc, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: So `Enum(struct)` is different from `Enum { .. }`?

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Yes. They look different and need different looking code, but fundamentally work the same way. The former has one tuple-like field with multiple fields whereas in the latter, access does not go through that one tuple-like field. The code semantics should be the same in both cases.

Comment: This is much cleaner than my approach and I like it.  Thanks for the advice.